# Whats the correct way to implement dockerfile if the requirements.txt exist in parent-child folder

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, requirements.txt

Issue in creating a dockerfile as I am getting a error that the `requirements.txt` file is not existing however it exists in the parent folder

I have a directory with the below given structure

```
Folder
|
|
--requirements.txt
|
|
--Sub_Folder
     |
     |
     --Dockerfile
```

However when I am trying to copy requirements.txt I am getting error that the file doesn't exist

```
COPY ..\requirements.txt .\
```

Comment: Can you move the `Dockerfile` up to the parent directory, next to your `setup.cfg` and `requirements.txt` files?  That'd be the easiest answer.